# Selecting features for classification model

Tags: classification, python, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have a dataset that contains some numeric variables. What im doing is trying to check how important these variables are in describing endogenous variable in order to include them in my classifier.

I understand that in order to do so, I need to check p-values of given variables and in order to do so, what I did is i tried to use f_classif and chi2.

I tried to do that in python the same way as in documentation (scikit learn), but i do not understand how to interpret the results. Moreover, in example on sklearn documentation I get this:

```
selector = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=4)
selector.fit(X_train, y_train)
scores = -np.log10(selector.pvalues_)
scores /= scores.max()
```

What does this transformation mean and how to interpret this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why are you doing forced-choice classification?

Comment: Why do you think that you "need to check p-values of given variables" (I assume you mean each on its own?)? I know this is sometimes done by people, which is where you may have seen this, but it's not a good practice.

Comment: Yep, I've seen it being done on some other model and if I recall correctly, it was done in order to identify variables that are not statistically significant and shall be dropped from the  model before building it. I am aware that I may use any form of regularization instead, I just wanted to understand what is it for and how to interpret this stuff, like chi2, anova and so on.

Comment: Is anyone able to help me?

Comment: You might have better luck if you rephrase the question to focus on the $-\log _{10} (p)$ transformation. As it stands, your main question is muddied by how it came up in the context of a poor practice (as @Björn has noted).

Comment: But that is actually what Im trying to understand - why is it a poor practice. In econometrics classes everyone emphasizes about feature importance and You guys are telling me it is irrelevant - I am trying to understand why? Especially if we have a variable that we know upfront that may be irrelevant to us as a predictor, yet we need to have a proof for that.

Comment: That’s really a separate question, one that [Frank Harrell](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/4253/frank-harrell) addresses [around the 18-minute mark of the keynote address here](https://youtube.com/watch?v=DF1WsYZ94Es) You might want to post a new question, since “What is minus log of a p-value?” is a separate issue from selecting features or determining feature importance.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation exists to put tiny numbers on a more meaningful scale. Humans see tiny p-values like $0.00001627$ and $0.0003119$ as just "tiny numbers". Try taking $-\log_{10}$ of those values; you will get $4.789$ and $3.506$. This emphasizes the difference between what might otherwise be seen as a tiny difference. "Tiny" vs "tiny" is harder to compare than $4.8$ vs $3.5$.

[Note, however, the issues with feature selection.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/579484)