# Univariable analysis and stepwise

Tags: multiple-regression

There are varied answers when building models for logistic regression.
For selection of predictors to build multivariable model :

1. should one choose from univariable analysis or stepwise
   Or
2. first do univariable analysis, then add significant associations by stepwise approach to build multivariable model ?

Comment: [Why not take all of the features?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/579484/247274)

Comment: You pose a false dichotomy.  We have many posts on model building -- and a [large number of them](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=model+building+stepwise) provide methods considered to be superior to stepwise methods.  We also have many posts that point out the (sharp) distinction between univariate regressions and multiple regression.  They imply that neither of your strategies is appropriate.